# Redirect Category Media 'URL' when clicked

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

Currently when I view the Media page the URL is /category/media/.

I need the URL redirected to /media/.

What's the easiest way to do in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a simple .htaccess fix, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: HI that did not work. If I have other categories is there another way of doing in WordPress admin.

Comment: Ok fixed the solution I had to restructure the blog. I was before using catgeory as the main posts page which is why I was having this issue.